# Toshiba Laptop can't find Ubuntu on boot

Tags: boot

I just installed ubuntu via a USB to my toshiba satellite laptop. Everything went fine as far as the install goes but when I go to restart so I can boot into the install the laptop can't find anything to boot off of. I went back into the live USB and everything was installed on the hard drive and if I try to re install it recognizes there is already a copy of the OS on the drive. Why won't the laptop find it? 
   p.s I had windows 8.1 before installing if that is of any importance.

Comment: Have you changed your boot order? Also, are you using BIOS or (U)EFI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want to look here and try it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

another possible answer here: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

sadly don't know if it is really the boatloader. would be good if some experienced user comments here

Comment: Did you totally delete Windows? And did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode or BIOS boot mode? Is UEFI/BIOS set for correct boot mode to match how you installed. Does f12 or whatever key is boot choice show Ubuntu? If not post link for summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I downloaded boot repair and it successfully fixed the problem! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

ok i hope its not to late but i had the same problem with my toshiba laptop so i brought it to a professional and he worked out that toshiba devices look for the boot file in the wrong spot so you need another pc or the live version of ubuntu and you need to move the boot file into a specific boot folder which i must apologies for not knowing but it ended up working for me (basically make the iso files look like that of a windows boot disk)